# cohomology of classifying space of cyclic group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

(1). Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $B\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the classifying space of the discrete group $\mathbb{Z}_p$. How to obtain
$$
H^*(B\mathbb{Z}_p;\mathbb{Z}_p)=\mathbb{Z}_p[t]\otimes \Lambda[e]?
$$
Here $\deg e=1$, $\deg t=2$?

(2). Let $q$ be another prime number larger than $p$. What is 
$$
H^*(B\mathbb{Z}_p;\mathbb{Z}_q)?
$$

(3). What is 
$$
H^*(B\mathbb{Z}_p;\mathbb{Q})?
$$

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the $p$-adic integers or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: it means $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. the p-adic integers is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: To make things even more confusing, $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ can also denote the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the ideal $(p)$. Probably wouldn't be useful in topology, though.

Comment: @anomaly : No, but in algebraic geometry yes (where we also compute cohomology often) where $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ is the stalk of the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ at $(p)$, and its importance is not to be denied.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Sure, algebraic geometry is full of cohomology theories. Good point.

Comment: This is false. Take $p = 2$ then $B\mathbb{Z}/2 = RP ^ \infty$ and the cohomology $H^*(RP^\infty, \mathbb{Z}/2) =  \mathbb{Z}/2[x]$.

Comment: @RSQ: Is the problem restricted to $p > 2$, or is there a different definition of $\Lambda[e]$ in the characteristic $2$ case? The periodicity argument should still apply for $p = 2$; the difference is that the generator $u\in \hat H^1$ no longer has $u^2 = 0$ (which in characteristic $\not= 2$ is just a consequence of the antisymmetry of the cup product).

Answer (score 3):

In this answer I'll assume that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

For 2), more generally, let $G$ be a finite group and let $q$ be a prime not dividing $|G|$. Then $H^n(BG, \mathbb{F}_q)$ vanishes (for $n \ge 1$). One of many ways to see this is that under the given hypotheses $\mathbb{F}_q[G]$ is semisimple and so the category of $\mathbb{F}_q[G]$-modules has no nontrivial higher Ext groups.

Comment: (3). What is 
$$
H^*(B\mathbb{Z}_p;\mathbb{Q})?
$$

Comment: @RSQ: it vanishes by a similar argument. $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ is semisimple.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify notation, write $\hat H^*$ for the Tate cohomology group $\hat H^*\left(\mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_p\right)$. Then $\hat H^*$ has period $2$; that is, the map $x\to x\cup u$ is an isomorphism $\hat H^* \to \hat H^{*+2}$ for some $u\in \hat H^2$. To prove this, consider the periodic complete resolution of $G$ via its action on $S^1$, for example, or compute $\hat H^2 = \mathbb{Z}_p$ directly and invoke duality. The low-dimensional $\hat H^*$ are easy to compute directly and then give you the required result for part (1). Parts (2) and (3) follow immediately, using the fact (proved via dimension-shifting, for example) that $\hat H^*$ vanishes if $|G| = p$ is invertible in $M$.

If you don't like using Tate cohomology, consider the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence corresponding to the fibration $S^1 \to S^1/\mathbb{Z}_p$, with $\mathbb{Z}_p$ acting by rotations. Since $H_*(S^1, \mathbb{Z}_p)$ vanishes above dimension $1$, the sequence should abut quickly. For parts (2) and (3), use the transfer map to prove that $H^n(G, M) = 0$ for $n > 0$ if $|G|$ is (finite and) invertible in $M$.